# UpdatePanel doesnt work with script manager. There is a postback happening for the code below. How do I do Ajax behavior?

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rpChat" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpChat_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rpChat_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="divChatWindow" title='<%# Eval("username") %>' runat="server" class="clChatWindow">
                        <div>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>' class="divHeader"></asp:Label>
                            <img src="../../Menu/close.jpg" onclick="HideDiv(this)" style="float: right; width: 20px;
                                height: 20px;" /></div>
                        <div class="chatText">
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rpChatMessages" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="imageForFriend" runat="server" CssClass="clFriendsImage" ImageUrl='<%# "HttpImageHandler.jpg?username=" +  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"fromusername").ToString() %>' />
                                    <asp:Label ID="chatMessage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    <br>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                        </div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtChatMessage" runat="server" Width="115px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSendChat" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("username") %>'>Send</asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have edited the code... Now what should I do? I have the linkbutton inside contenttemplate. Still a postback is happening

Answer (score 1):

Any postback coming from any control outside an `UpdatePanel` will trigger a full postback unless you add those events as triggers of your `UpdatePanel`

In your example,

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSendChat" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Username2") %>'>Send</asp:LinkButton>
```

It's outside of the `UpdatePanel` and since you do not have triggers in your panel that will always cause a full postback

Solutions:

### Approach 1

Place the `LinkButton` inside the `UpdatePanel.ContentTemplate`

### Approach 2

Add triggers to your `UpdatePanel`

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSendChat" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: repeater triggers an itemcommand. So How do I set it up in triggers

Comment: I just saw your update, try adding `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"` to your update pannel